# Testing IAP edge cases in iOS (eg: missing credit card info, etc.)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, credit-card

We currently have an app in the app store that uses IAP to disable ads and add a few features.

However, we've noticed that some users have problems buying the IAP. After scrutiny it seems most of it comes down to not having an active internet connection on the moment of purchase. About a dozen cases however could not be tracked down and resolved.

One of these:

1. tap buy IAP
2. Credit Card security code was not yet filled in
3. purchase fails
4. user is automatically moved to his App Store account to fill in the missing code
5. user fills in code and confirms buying the IAP
6. user goes back to the app
7. purchase is still failed (!)

Conclusion: user paid and did not yet receive the IAP. 
(of course this can be resolved by tapping the IAP again and downloading for free, but that's not ideal)

We're looking to test a solution to such edge cases.
However test accounts usually do not require valid CC info. Thus..

Question: How do I test such cases?

Comment: Excellent question. One way, in production, involving your own money would be to use your own card. Not ideal, I know since you may want to run this test many times. I'd submit this to Apple as a bug if I were you. Apple should provide better test coverage. Eg, fake credit cards for sandbox accounts. Its a pretty big leap of faith for Apple to believe sandbox is equivalent to production given the lack of credit card info.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Production purchases are not ideal indeed, as it would involve sending out a version without testing. And of course there's the practical side of running the test multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using prepaid credit cards to test and make sure it goes through.

Comment: Have you been able to test using a test account, or only when the version was in the App Store?